# Python and gmail

Tags: python-2.7, gmail, poplib

I try to get email from gmail:

```
box = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
print box.getwelcome()
print box.user(user)
print box.pass_(password)
print box.list()
```

but I get:

```
+OK Gpop ready for requests from #######
+OK send PASS
+OK Welcome.
('+OK 0 messages (0 bytes)', [], 0)
```

and my gmail not empty. What wrong?
python ver 2.7

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/robulouski/7441883

This will surely help you to fetch the mails from gmail.
try out.